# A persistent error: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to register Users but this throws A non-null String that must be provided to a Text widget error. I have gone through the code to check if I have given a null value to any Text Widget but I couldn't find one as all Text widgets are null sound.

Below is an excerpt of the code

```
ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: ProjectColors.primary,
          minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(height * 0.08),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Register',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            _formKey.currentState!.save();

            await authController.createUserAccount(context);
          }
        },
      ),
```

**when I start debugging, the error seems to be pointed at * await authController.createUserAccount(context);* ** and this is confusing me the more.

**This is the createUserAccount function**

```
AuthService authService = AuthService();
  ProjectApis projectApis = ProjectApis();

  String name = '';
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String confirmPassword = '';
  var isPasswordHidden = true.obs;

  Future createUserAccount(BuildContext context) async {
   //show loader here

    http.Response response = await authService.signUpUser(
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
    );

   
    if (response.statusCode == 200 && response. Body != "") {
      Map<String, dynamic> res = json.decode(response. Body);
      
      if (res["status"] == true) {
        var user = User.fromJson(res["data"]);
        
        UserPreferences().setUser(user);
        
        Get.offAll(() => GoHome());
        return;

      } else {
        print(res['message']);
        return;
      }
    } else {
     
     Text("Error Occurred");
      return;
    }
  }
```

**And this is the signUpUser function**

```
Future<http.Response> signUpUser({
String? name,
String? email,
String? password,
String? confirmPassword,


}) async {
    Map data = {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'password_confirmation': confirmPassword,
    };
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var url = Uri.parse(projectApis.registerUrl);

    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: body,
      headers: projectApis.headers,
    );
   
    return response;
  }
```

I have read through this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597784/a-non-null-string-must-be-provided-to-a-text-widget-packageflutter-src-widget) and this [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68708467/a-non-null-string-must-be-provided-to-a-text-widget-packageflutter-src-widget)

but none of them solve my problem.

Comment: Please add this method authController.createUserAccount(context)

Comment: @KaushikChandru please I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

In the createUserAccount method you returned a Text widget.  This is creating an error i think

```dart
Text("Error Occurred");
```

Replace this with a print statement for testing

```dart
Print("Error Occurred");
```

Comment: That's not really the course of the error though. I have just tried. But thanks for pointing that out

Comment: What other lines is it throwing an error in?

Comment: Its pointing to the same line, so I want to believe the error is in createUserAccount method